# Spring Boot not connecting to redis running on WSL

Tags: spring-boot, redis, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have followed the instructions here:

https://redis.io/docs/getting-started/installation/install-redis-on-windows/

to run redis on windows. This works well and if I run redis-server --port 6380 I see:

```
          _._
       _.-``__ ''-._
  _.-``    `.  `_.  ''-._           Redis 6.0.16 (00000000/0) 64 bit
```

.- ```` .-```.  ```\/    _.,_ ''-._ (    '      ,       .-`  | `,    )     Running in standalone mode |`-._`-...-` __...-. ````-.*|'`_.-'|     Port: 6380 |`   -.*   `._    /     _.-'    |     PID: 1023` -._    `-._`  -./  *.-'    *.-'
|`-._`-.*    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'| |`    -.*`-._        _.-'_.-'    |           http://redis.io` -._    `-._`-.**.-'*.-'    *.-'
|`-._`-.*    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'| |`    -.*`-._        _.-'_.-'    |` -._    `-._`-.**.-'_.-'    _.-'
`-._`    -.**.-'    _.-'
`-._        _.-'` -.**.-'

Now I am trying to connecting to this redis instance using spring boot. I have a bean that uses the create method of Redisson:

```
public RedissonClient client(Config config){
       return Redisson.create(config);
}
```

When I debug this line of code I end up seeing the following error message:

io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:6380

It looks like the redis instance is not being exposed to the other applications running on my machine because when I run netstat -ona | findstr 6380 the answer is empty on cmd.

Is there something else I need to do after having redis running on WSL (ubuntu) in order to connect to it ?